# ALSA/ASoC: How to correctly load devices/drivers?

Tags: kernel-modules, alsa

I am using Buildroot to build an embedded Linux (2.6.39.2) system for the NXP LPC3250 microcontroller.

Right now, I'm trying to get ALSA/ASoC up and running, but I'm having some issues with getting the modules to work together. (I think!)

### Some important background:

The board I am testing with is the [Embedded Artists 3250 V2 development board](http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/kits/lpc3250_kit_v2.php). V2 is different from V1 in that it does not have an LCD screen, but *does include* an I2S audio codec: The NXP UDA1380. Board support for EA3250 **V1** is included in the [LPCLinux](http://git.lpclinux.com/) version of the kernel. There is also a different development board, called [Phytec 3250](http://www.phytec.com/products/rdk/ARM-XScale/phyCORE-ARM9-LPC3250.html), which contains the same UDA1380 codec chip. The LPCLinux distribution also has support for the Phytec board, along with the audio codec chip. From what I have discerned, the Phytec 3250 board has the UDA1380 codec on I2C address **0x18**. On my EA3250 V2 board, the audio codec is located at I2C address **0x1a**. *(I have verified the chip is powered up, and I can communicate to it by using the I2C-tools package. It responds to i2cdetect and I can read registers from the chip correctly using i2cget.)*

### Modifying the source:

I needed to edit the Phytec 3250 driver files to change the address of the codec chip. I edited this section of [lpc3xxx-uda1380.c](http://goo.gl/j4xF5):

```
static struct snd_soc_dai_link phy3250_uda1380_dai[] = {
       {
                  .name           = "uda1380",
                  .stream_name    = "UDA1380 Duplex",
  #if defined(CONFIG_SND_LPC32XX_USEI2S1)
                  .cpu_dai_name   = "lpc3xxx-i2s1",
  #else
                  .cpu_dai_name   = "lpc3xxx-i2s0",
  #endif
                  .codec_dai_name = "uda1380-hifi",
                  .init           = phy3250_uda1380_init,
                  .platform_name  = "lpc3xxx-audio.0",
         //EDIT// .codec_name     = "uda1380-codec.0-0018",  //EDIT//
                  .codec_name     = "uda1380-codec.0-001a",
                  .ops            = &phy3250_uda1380_ops,
          },
  };
```

After I made this change, I went ahead and built the system again and everything compiled OK. After booting into the system, I have the following modules (in addition to the standard core modules) in `/lib/modules/2.6.39.2/kernel/sound`:

```
 ./soc/codecs: snd-soc-uda1380.ko          <-- ASoC codec driver
./soc/lpc3xxx: snd-soc-lpc3xxx-i2s.ko      <-- ASoC DAI
               snd-soc-lpc3xxx-uda1380.ko  <-- ASoC machine driver
               snd-soc-lpc3xxx.ko          <-- ASoC platform driver
```

***Now, how do I actually bind all this stuff together?***

Just inserting the modules with `modprobe` doesn't actually give the device to ALSA/ASoC. I am unable to detect the soundcard. Does this mean I must now make a new device called `uda1380-codec` at address **0x1a** and bind it to a driver? I have tried doing the following:
`echo uda1380-codec 0x01a > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/new_device` 
and received: 
`i2c  i2c-0: new_device: Instantiated device uda1380-codec at 0x1a`
Then I try to bind a driver to the device:
`echo 0x1a > /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/uda1380-codec/bind` 
and received: 
`sh: write error: No such device`
I get this error for everything I try! I have a feeling I am not creating the device correctly, and then I'm not sure how to bind it to the correct driver.

### Nota Bene:

I was playing with this last night and was somehow able to get ASoC to wake up and at least probe for the card. I was playing with different bindings, I guess. It was late and hard to remember my steps, but I was able to at least get the following error somehow:

```
uda1380-codec 0-001a: asoc: failed to probe CODEC uda1380-codec.0-001a: -22
asoc: failed to instantiate card LPC32XX: -22
```

I have been unable to recreate this error!

### Edit:

I've confirmed my modified code is being compiled, so the driver should be talking to the correct address now. After manually loading the modules, the output of `lsmod` is:

```
Module                      Size  Used by    Not tainted
snd_soc_lpc3xxx_uda1380     2087  0 
snd_soc_lpc3xxx             3089  0 
snd_soc_lpc3xxx_i2s         4089  1 
snd_soc_uda1380            10865  0 
snd_soc_core               51549  4 snd_soc_lpc3xxx_uda1380,snd_soc_lpc3xxx,snd_soc_lpc3xxx_i2s,snd_soc_uda1380
snd_pcm                    52098  2 snd_soc_lpc3xxx,snd_soc_core
snd_timer                  15590  1 snd_pcm
snd_page_alloc              3021  1 snd_pcm
snd                        37286  3 snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_timer
```

Does this look right?

And my device table:

```
# Audio stuff
/dev/audio      c       666     0       29      14      4       -       -       -
#/dev/audio1    c       666     0       29      14      20      -       -       -
/dev/dsp        c       666     0       29      14      3       -       -       -
#/dev/dsp1      c       666     0       29      14      19      -       -       -
#/dev/sndstat   c       666     0       29      14      6       -       -       -
/dev/mixer      c       666     0       29      14      0       -       -       -
/dev/snd        d       755     0       29      -       -       -       -       -
/dev/snd/controlC0      c       666     0       29      116     0       -       -       -
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c       c       666     0       29      116     24      -       -       -
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p       c       666     0       29      116     16      -       -       -
/dev/snd/seq    c       666     0       29      116     1       -       -       -
/dev/snd/timer  c       666     0       29      116     33      -       -       -
```

Comment: You should read the ASoC documentation, and then ask on the `alsa-devel` list (where you will be told that 2.6.39 is horribly outdated, and that the board vendor is responsible for support).

Comment: @CL. Thanks, board vendor does not support UDA1380 codec with LPCLinux *(I have already contacted them)*, which is why I'm trying to hack it in myself.

Comment: I posted to ``alsa-devel`` and nobody responded. (That I can tell - I hate mail-lists, they are the worst to read through.) Now my mailbox is full of ALSA crap and I still have no help. Here I go again, on my own...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to edit the board's file that defines platform devices. I needed to modify `arch/arm/mach-lpc32xx/ea3250.c` :

Add this:

```
/*
 * Platform Data for UDA1380 Audiocodec.
 * As there are no GPIOs for codec power & reset pins,
 * dummy GPIO numbers are used.
 */
static struct uda1380_platform_data uda1380_info = {
    .gpio_power = LPC32XX_GPIO(LPC32XX_GPO_P3_GRP,10),
    .gpio_reset = LPC32XX_GPIO(LPC32XX_GPO_P3_GRP,2),
    .dac_clk    = UDA1380_DAC_CLK_WSPLL,
};
```

Edit this to include the codec:

```
static struct i2c_board_info __initdata ea3250_i2c_board_info [] = {
        {   I2C_BOARD_INFO("uda1380", 0x1a),
            .platform_data = &uda1380_info,
        }, 
#if defined (CONFIG_LEDS_PCA9532)
        {
            I2C_BOARD_INFO("pca9532", I2C_PCA9532_ADDR),
            .platform_data = &ea3250_leds,
        },
#endif
#if defined (CONFIG_FB_ARMCLCD)
        {
            /* 8Kb Configuration EEPROM on display board */
            I2C_BOARD_INFO("ea_i2c_disp_cfg", LCDB_CONFIG_EEPROM_I2C_ADDR),
        },
        {
            I2C_BOARD_INFO("ea_i2c_video", LCDB_PCA9532_I2C_ADDR),
        },
#endif
#if defined (CONFIG_EEPROM_AT24)
        {
            I2C_BOARD_INFO("24c256", I2C_24LC256_ADDR),
        },
#endif
    };
#endif
```

Now I have all the devices:

```
# cat cards
 0 [LPC32XX        ]:  - LPC32XX
                      LPC32XX
# cat devices
  2: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  3: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  4: [ 0]   : control
 33:        : timer

# cat pcm
00-00: UDA1380 Duplex uda1380-hifi-0 :  : playback 1 : capture 1
```

I can't get `aplay` to detect anything yet though, but perhaps that is a different issue.

EDIT: Yes, that was a different issue. The number in front of the devices shown by `cat devices` should match the Minor device number in your /dev/snd device entries. Everything seems good on ALSA end now, but I have no I2S data coming from the LPC3250...

EDIT2: SOLVED SOLVED SOLVED. If you there's no I2S data/clock, make sure the output mux register is configured correctly to connect the output pins to the I2S peripheral!!!