# Linux via Buildroot doesn't include alsa-utils

Tags: linux, alsa, buildroot

After following these instructions from [here](http://www.arm9board.net/wiki/index.php?title=ALSA_Sound_setup) and from [here](http://elasticsheep.com/2011/01/adding-alsa-audio-support-to-a-buildroot-based-system/), my booted Linux does not include ALSA-Utils like "aplay". But I have set all ALSA options. Any idea what's wrong?

I also found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59497/alsa-asoc-how-to-correctly-load-devices-drivers) but I can't imagine that code refactoring will suddenly include these ALSA-Utils.

Answer (score 1):

I backed up my .config file and did a `make distclean`, copied the .config back and after `make` the uImage contained the correct files.

Comment: Worked for me too