# How to configure buildroot to add a sound device?

Tags: drivers, audio, kernel-modules, alsa, buildroot

I've used a given board configuration to reconfigure it for my individual board. My board has a CS4270 sound device of Cirrus Logic. My uImage is booting successfully on my target hardware, but an `alsactl init` always shows me `no sound card`. I loaded as many sound modules as I can, e.g. `modprobe snd-soc-cs4270`. But I have the feeling there is one module missing because the [alsa-project website](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-cs4270) shows a specific module named `snd-cs4270`. Can I get this module installed by buildroot or do I have to download and integrate it into my target hardware on my own?

I've followed [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59497/alsa-asoc-how-to-correctly-load-devices-drivers) and ended up with the question, if I must implement the sound device in the board file in `linux/linux-kernel/arch/<my_arch>/mach-<board_arch>/<board>.c`. But this can't give me a `snd-cs4270`module.

Has anyone an idea which way I shall go to get this thing done?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed:

Try adding **dtparam=audio=on** to **/boot/config.txt**

Source:[Fix for issue ALSA says no sound card on Raspberrypi 2/3](https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/alsa-doesnt-work-after-last-update/10600/2)